# Why do I need to "from tqdm import tqdm" instead of just "import tqdm"?

Tags: python, python-import, libraries, python-module, tqdm

Probably a simple question, but I'm just getting started with Python and try to understand how the library stuff works.

So my question is why do I need to type

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

instead of just

```
import tqdm
```

like with other libraries?

I get that when you only need one part of a library you can do this. But in this case my program doesn't work if I don't do it. Shouldn't be everything included with the second expression?
If I run my program with it I get the error:

> "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Comment: It's so you just have to type `tqdm()` and not `tqdm.tqdm()` every time.

Comment: You *don't have to*. When you do `from some_module import some_name` then you import the whole module, and assign `some_name` to `some_name` in that scope. If you use `import tqdm` you could use `tqdm.tqdm`, it just happens to use the same name as the module. Indeed, `import tqdm` would generally be preffered

Comment: Now, `some_name` may itself be another module, but it doesn't have to be. And in the case of `tqdm.tqdm` it is not. Here is the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `tqdm` has a module named `tqdm` inside it. Now to your `tqdm` you can

1. Import all the modules in package `tqdm` and use the module called `tqdm` by:

```
import tqdm

for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(10)):
  pass
```

OR

2. Just import the `tqdm` module of the `tqdm` package by:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
  pass
```

Comment: *No there is no module `tqdm.tqdm`*

Comment: Ah thank you! I was just confused because it has the same name, didn't know that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

`from tqdm import tqdm` means you're importing module tqdm under tqdm.

`import tqdm` means importing whole package. In this case you've to use `tqdm.tqdm()` which is equivalent to using just `tqdm()` in the above case.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that in this case. There is a single module, `tqdm` which has a name, `tqdm` in it.

Answer (score 0):

The first `tqdm` is the name of the package or module. The second `tqdm` is a callable defined under that package/module. It could have been a different callable, such as `trange`:

```py
from tqdm import trange
```

What you are basically doing is importing the tqdm callable inside the tqdm module.

Comment: No, it is *not equivalent* to `import tqdm.tqdm as tqdm`. There is no module named `tqdm.tqdm`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I mixed up with another library.