# Why does "from module import module" solve the no attribute problem?

Tags: python

I was tinkering around with a module called pixray.

```
import pixray
pixray.reset_settings()
```

The above code returned the error "module 'pixray' has no attribute 'reset_settings'"

But when I changed it to:

```
from pixray import pixray
pixray.reset_settings()
```

The code is able to run.

Not sure why this is the case.

Any and all explanations are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: first: `pixray.reset_settings()`, second: `pixray.pixray.reset_settings()`.

Comment: Since this package isn't on PyPI and you're probably getting it from here, https://github.com/pixray/pixray, it looks like it hasn't really been set up as a proper Python package, so it's not easy to say. Normally, when what you're describing happens, there's something inside the `pixray` package, which would also be called `pixray`. For example a class or module called `pixray` inside the `pixray` package. The second example gets that contained module, class or whatever and adds it to the global namespace of wherever you're importing it, instead of adding the package itself.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225241/why-do-i-need-to-from-tqdm-import-tqdm-instead-of-just-import-tqdm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier to demonstrate with an example from within python's standard library - datetime!

```
import datetime 

print(type(datetime)) # <class 'module'>

print(datetime.now())
# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

print(datetime.datetime.now())
# no error
```

```
from datetime import datetime

print(type(datetime)) # <class 'type'>

print(datetime.now())
# no error
```

See, the  module `datetime` exposes several objects: 'date', 'datetime', 'time', 'timedelta', 'timezone', 'tzinfo'. When you do `import datetime`, what you're doing is assigning the local name "datetime" to this module, which has those properties. Note that one of those properties is, in fact, also called "datetime".

Now, if you were to do `from datetime import date`, then what python would do is load the datetime module, retrieve the `date` object within, and then assign that to the local name "date", *without also assigning the module `datetime` to any local variable*.

Similarly, if you were to do `from datetime import datetime`, then python will load the `datetime` object from the `datetime` module, and assign that to the local name "datetime".

The same thing is likely happening in your case, except the name is `pixray`, not `datetime`. That is, **the module `pixray` happens to contain an object, also called `pixray`, which has all the useful functionality. `import pixray` gives you the module, whereas `from pixray import pixray` gives you the object.**